# How to sleep with read in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, sleep

With bash I can

```
read -N 1000 -t 10
```

to sleep 10 seconds, the `-N` is for when I type something in the terminal, if less then 1000 characters, the sleep will continue.

But with zsh

```
read -k 1000 -t 10
```

If I type any character, it will sleep forever.

Comment: Bash's read doesn't have a -k option and zsh's doesn't have a -N. But vis versa, they do. Are you getting your examples reversed?

Comment: In addition to what Shawn said, note that the `read` command in _bash_ has the options `-N` **and** `-n`, which behave differently. `-N` would require exactly that number of characters to be entered, while `-n` is also happy with fewer charactes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer somewhere else.

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
zselect -t 500
```

to sleep for 5 seconds